# How to use RBStoryboardLink with embed segues across multiple storyboard files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been using [RBStoryboardLink](https://github.com/rob-brown/RBStoryboardLink) to break up a monolithic iOS storyboard file into a number of more manageable storyboards. RBStoryboardLink comes with support for allowing Push, Popover and Modal segues to transition across storyboard files, but I was looking for a solution to handle embed segues as well.

Not finding anything obvious with an online search, I've documented my solution in an answer below in case it's of use for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update for Xcode 7**

As of Xcode 7 use of RBStoryboardLink may be replaced with the native *[Storyboard reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html)* feature which also allows segues across storyboards. It's only available for apps targeting iOS 8, 10.10 and Watch OS 1 (refer to the Xcode [7.0 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc7_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH5-SW29)).

**Original answer**

WARNING: This solution involves hand-editing the storyboard XML file as Xcode's Interface Builder UI doesn't allow specifying a custom class for Embed segues. Use this method at your own risk!

Familiarise yourself with the instructions for using RBStoryboardLink. The method follows more or less the same procedure, with some additional steps at the end for editing the storyboard XML.

1. Sub-class RBStoryboardSegue:

   ```
   @interface RBStoryboardEmbedSegue : RBStoryboardSegue
   @end
   @implementation RBStoryboardEmbedSegue

   - (void)perform
   {
       // Manually simulate an 'embed' segue. Local UIViewController variables avoid compiler warnings in Xcode 6.0b5.
       UIViewController* source = self.sourceViewController;
       UIViewController* destination = self.destinationViewController;
       [source addChildViewController:destination];
       [source.view addSubview:destination.view];
       [destination didMoveToParentViewController:source];
   }
   @end
   ```
2. In Interface Builder, drop a Container View into the parent view controller. Interface Builder creates the embed segue and a target UIViewController for you. This target view controller will act as the 'surrogate' for the 'real' view controller which is residing in some other storyboard file.
3. Set the class of the target UIViewContoller just created to RBStoryboardLink.
4. Set the appropriate User Defined Runtime Attributes on the surrogate view controller. At a minimum, set *storyboardName* to the name of the 'other' storyboard file (don't include any path extension) which contains the real target view controller that you want embedded at runtime.
5. Select the newly created embed segue and give it a unique identifier in Interface Builder's Attribute Inspector.
6. As Interface Builder's UI doesn't permit specifying a custom embed segue class, we need to do this manually. Open the storyboard file containing the embed segue in an XML editor and search for your segue's unique identifier. It will be in a *<segue>* element and will look something like this:

   ```
   <segue destination="0yd-AT-CHi" kind="embed" identifier="MySegue" id="kx9-F0-BST"/>
   ```
7. Set the custom class of the segue by adding a *customClass* attribute to the *segue* element:

   ```
   <segue destination="0yd-AT-CHi" kind="embed" identifier="MySegue" customClass="RBStoryboardEmbedSegue" id="kx9-F0-BST"/>
   ```
8. Build and run your app.

Xcode's Interface Builder's Attributes Inspector doesn't recognise the custom class attribute, so it's quite possible that some Interface Builder editing operations (such as editing the segue's Identifier) may re-write the segue element and omit the hand-edited changes. (I've submitted Radar/Bug Report 17987173 to Apple requesting proper support for custom embed segue classes.)

For the curious, changing the *kind* attribute's value from *embed* to *custom* doesn't give the desired result. It generates a runtime exception along the lines of "[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key containerView.".